# java.sql.SQLException: No current row in the ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using the `jtbs.jdbc.Driver` to verify that a proxy number is stored in my MySQL database.

The problem is that whenever I try to copy the curtain row from the table and put it in my `ResultSet`, the error says that 
`there is no current row in the ResultSet`

The error is at line 31 `String value = result.getString(i);`

i have been looking all over the web for answers but none of them seem to help my specific predicament.

**UP DATE**
so far i added a `while(result.next())` and it basically dose nothing the `while(result.next())` dose not execute.

Here's my code!!!

```
    package dataBata;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class apples {

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String proxNumber = "2435847564";
    String usersName = "user";
    String password = "pass";

    public void wrightMatchdb(){
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/model";

    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usersName, password);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select replace(PROXID , ' ','') PROXID ,FIRST_NAME from OKWC_IDCARDS where PROXID = '" + proxNumber + "'");
        System.out.println("hello");
        while(result.next()){
            for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
                System.out.println("hello2");
                String value = result.getString(i);

                if(result.getString(i) != null){
                    value = value.replace(" ","");
                    myList.add(value);
                }
                String userProx=myList.get(i);
                String userFName=myList.get(i+1);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userProx + " has a match for", "hi " + userFName, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
            }
            System.out.println("hello3");
        };
        System.out.println("hello4");
        statement.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        apples A = new apples();
        A.wrightMatchdb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`result.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) before calling `result.getString(i)`

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A
>   `ResultSet` cursor **is initially positioned before the first row;** the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

---

As far as I can see, your query **returns only 2 columns** so if you call `result.getString(i)`, make sure that `i` is either `1` or `2` otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Thank you I'll implement that in to my code when i have access to my database on Monday.

Comment: i tried the `result.next()` in a while loop but its only causing the program to not execute the commands in the while loop. ill update my program so you can see what i'm taking about

Comment: probably because you loop on the columns with for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){ knowing that you have only 3 columns (PROXID ,FIRST_NAME) and you call myList.get(i+1); to get a value that doesn't seem to be added yet => IndexOutOfBoundsException